# Which are the best methods for speeding up the algorithm based on vector search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, indexing

I am trying to solve the [Euler question 419](https://projecteuler.net/problem=419)

So far, I think I managed to build an algorithm to find the answer. Or at least it gives the correct result for first 40 step. But I need to compute 1,000,000,000,000th step. Solving first 40 step (with my algorithm) takes about 3-4 seconds. And bigger the iteration number increases, computation time increases as well. I don't think my computer can solve 1,000,000,000,000 iteration in a year.

What I do is simply using temporary vectors for both sequential number counting(form_1 and form_2) and keeping the calculated the result for each iteration(testVec). Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<int> form_1;
std::vector<int> form_2;
std::vector<int> testVec;

void showVec(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    //
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        //
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void resFin(int start, int stop, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    //
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        //
        if (i == 0)
        {
            //
            form_1.push_back(vec[0]);
            //std::cout << "form_1 pushed " << vec[0] << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //
            if (i != vec.size() - 1)
            {
                //
                if (vec[i] == vec[i - 1])
                {
                    //
                    form_1.push_back(vec[i]);
                    //std::cout << "form_1 pushed " << vec[i] << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                    form_2.push_back(form_1.size());
                    form_2.push_back(vec[i - 1]);
                    form_1.clear();
                    form_1.push_back(vec[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //
                if (vec[i] == vec[i - 1])
                {
                    //
                    form_1.push_back(vec[i]);
                    //std::cout << "form_1 pushed " << vec[i] << std::endl;
                    form_2.push_back(form_1.size());
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << form_1.size() << std::endl;
                    form_2.push_back(vec[i - 1]);
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << vec[i - 1] << std::endl;
                    form_1.clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    //
                    form_2.push_back(form_1.size());
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << form_1.size() << std::endl;
                    form_2.push_back(vec[i - 1]);
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << vec[i - 1] << std::endl;
                    form_2.push_back(1);
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << 1 << std::endl;
                    form_2.push_back(vec[i]);
                    //std::cout << "form_2 pushed " << vec[i] << std::endl;
                    form_1.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vec.clear();
    for (unsigned long int k = 0; k < form_2.size(); k++)
    {
        //
        vec.push_back(form_2[k]);
        //std::cout << "vec pushed " << form_2[k] << std::endl;
    }
    //showVec(vec);
    if (start + 1 != stop)
    {
        //
        form_1.clear();
        form_2.clear();
        std::cout << "recursed to " << start + 1 << std::endl;
        resFin(start + 1, stop, vec);
    }
}

void stepFind(int stop, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    //
    resFin(1, stop, vec);
}

void trimmVec(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    //
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++)
    {
        //
        switch (vec[i])
        {
        case 1:
            a++;
            a = a % 1073741824;
            break;
        case 2:
            b++;
            b = b % 1073741824;
            break;
        case 3:
            c++;
            c = c % 1073741824;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "a is " << a << "; b is " << b << "; c is " << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    //
    testVec.push_back(1);
    testVec.push_back(1);
    stepFind(39, testVec);
    //showVec(testVec);
    trimmVec(testVec);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I think no one ought to wait more than a few hours to solve euler problems right? So I am doing something wrong here. So, are there such methods existed to minimize computing time, especially in vectors inside searching(I think this consumes the time most)?

Comment: *So far, I think I managed to build an algorithm to find the answer* -- Maybe you need a different algorithm.

Comment: Really? Man, I worked for many hours to come up with this algorithm. If this is rubbish, I ll be devastated. You think this algorithm is bad?

Comment: One trick to these online coding sites is that there is always a known algorithm that is out there that you should be using.  If you're coming up with your own algorithm, it is almost always the incorrect choice.

Comment: It is hard to understand. How does one search for a specific algorithm online? I can not think of even a keyword for that?!

Comment: Either an algorithm or a better, more efficient data structure that has faster lookups, insertions, etc, such as `std::map` or a hash table.

Comment: @LuckyB Euler questions are designed to be solved by students and hobbyists. (Neither of which have a tendency to possess high end super computers.) Thus, if a super computer (Basically absurd amounts of processing power) is required to solve the problem, then your algorithm is generally wrong. (Just think about it this way, they have to have gotten an answer for the problem, and they have some 500+ problems on that site. (Yet the internet sadly has been around for less than 500 years.) Thus, there must be some efficient method of finding the answer.)

Comment: You can also use your current, pretty explicit algorithm to find patterns and properties of the sequence, which may help you to find a better algorithm.

Comment: @LuckyB Also as a specific fact about that problem, take a look that it is looking for an answer `Give your answer modulo 2^30`, that should give some hint as to how you should be developing an algorithm if you can't find an existing one. (Between this and the patterns that should emerge, you should be able to find an efficient method of analyzing this problem.)